# Using python regex to find repeated values after a header

Tags: regex, python-2.7

If I have a string that looks something like:

```
s = """
...
Random Stuff
...
HEADER
a 1
a 3
# random amount of rows
a 17
RANDOM_NEW_HEADER
a 200
a 300
...
More random stuff
...
"""
```

Is there a clean way to use regex (in Python)  to find all instances of `a \d*` after HEADER, but before the pattern is broken by SOMETHING_TOTALLY_DIFFERENT? I thought about something like:

```
import re
pattern = r'HEADER(?:\na \d*)*\na (\d*)'

print re.findall(pattern, s)
```

Unfortunately, regex doesn't find overlapping matches. If there's no sensible way to do this with regex, I'm okay with anything faster than writing my own for loop to extract this data.

(TL;DR -- There's a distinct header, followed by a pattern that repeats. I want to catch each instance of that pattern, as long as there isn't a break in the repetition.)

EDIT:

To clarify, I don't necessarily know what SOMETHING_TOTALLY_DIFFERENT will be, only that it won't match `a \d+`. I want to collect all consecutive instances of `\na \d+` that follow `HEADER\n`.

Answer (score 2):

How about a simple loop?

```
import re

e = re.compile(r'(a\s+\d+)')

header = 'whatever your header field is'
breaker = 'something_different'

breaker_reached = False
header_reached = False

results = []

with open('yourfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line == header:
            # skip processing lines unless we reach the header
            header_reached = True
            continue
        if header_reached:
            i = e.match(line)
            if i and not breaker_reached:
               results.append(i.groups()[0])
            else:
               # There was no match, check if we reached the breaker
               if line == breaker:
                   breaker_reached = True
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid a for loop for performance reasons, but I can tweak this a bit to get it working. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Not completly sure where you want the regex to stop please clarify

> '((a \d*)\s){1,}'

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

sentinel_begin = 'HEADER'
sentinel_end = 'SOMETHING_TOTALLY_DIFFERENT'
re.findall(r'(a \d*)', s[s.find(sentinel_begin): s.find(sentinel_end)])
```